# how to implement a forum and article management system together

Tags: spring, content-management-system, spring-security, jackrabbit, magnolia

I want to create an article management system on wildlife and want to have a forum related to each article. How can I implement it. Following are the technologies I am familiar with Spring framework using Spring Security using MYSQL. Is there any open source avaialable for this kind of requirement. I want users to be able to publish their article and toehr people can ask the questions on those articles. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a blog to me. Articles plus comments. There are so many off the shelf solutions for this you should not ever build it yourself.

Maybe go with something like [wordpress](http://wordpress.org/).

Comment: If its a blog do you know any open source in Java

Comment: Is there any open source in Java just like stack overflow.